# FATAL EXCEPTION : main on Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

Hi i am novice with android this is my first time with sqlite while i try to add or read from database i keep getting fatal exception:main.

**Signup.java**

`Signup.java` is a activity called by main activity

```
public class Signup extends Activity

{

MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);  
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    TextView user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EUser); 
    TextView pass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EPass);
    TextView conpass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ConEPass);

    String userid = user.getText().toString();
    String password = pass.getText().toString();
    String confirmpass = conpass.getText().toString();

    if(userid.equals("") || password.equals("") || confirmpass.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all fields",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        user.setText("");
        pass.setText("");
        conpass.setText("");
    }   
    else if(!password.equals(confirmpass)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords don't match, please enter again",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pass.setText("");
        conpass.setText("");
    }
    else if(!db.getUserId(userid)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user id alreddy exists, please enter a new one",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        user.setText("");
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signing up ..............",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.insertUser(userid,password);
        Intent i = new Intent(Signup.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

MySQLiteHelper.java:-

```
public class MySQLiteHelper{

private static final String LOGCAT = null;  

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "User.db";

private static final String DATABASE_USERS = "Users";

private static final String KEY_USERID = "userid";

private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_USERID,KEY_PASSWORD};

private static final String TABLE_USERS = "create table "+DATABASE_USERS+" (userid TEXT, password TEXT)";

private SQLiteDatabase SQLdb;

private HelperClass helper;

private final Context mContext;

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context){
    this.mContext=context;
    helper = new HelperClass(mContext);
}

public class HelperClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public HelperClass(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase SQLdb){
        try{
            SQLdb.execSQL(TABLE_USERS);
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Table Created");
        }
        catch(SQLException e){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase SQLdb, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        SQLdb.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users");
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"Table being recreated");
        onCreate(SQLdb);
    }
}

public MySQLiteHelper open(){
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "trying to open");
    SQLdb = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    helper.close();
}

public void insertUser(String Userid,String Password){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_USERID,Userid);
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, Password);
    open();
    SQLdb.insert(DATABASE_USERS,null,values);
    close();
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "Inserted User");
}

public boolean getUserId(String userid){
    open();
    Cursor cursor = SQLdb.query(true,DATABASE_USERS,COLUMNS,KEY_USERID+"="+userid,null,null,null,null,null);//log shows as error
    close();
    if(cursor!=null){
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Found userid in DB");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Userid not found in DB");
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean getPassword(String password){
    open();
    Cursor cursor = SQLdb.query(true,DATABASE_USERS,COLUMNS,KEY_PASSWORD+"="+password,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor!=null){
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Found password in DB");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Password not found in DB");
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

these are the logs

> 01-24 16:46:19.024: E/SQLiteLog(12259): (1) no such column: lxnv
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259): Process: com.lxnv.myfirstapp, PID: 12259
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    ... 11 more
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: lxnv(code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT userid, password FROM Users WHERE userid=lxnv
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at com.lxnv.myfirstapp.MySQLiteHelper.getUserId(MySQLiteHelper.java:76)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at com.lxnv.myfirstapp.Signup.onClick(Signup.java:43)
>   01-24 16:46:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    ... 14 more

Comment: why are you passing null in the constructor of MySQLiteHelper class?

Comment: sorry i had put up an old Verison, and i also commented out the part i think is wrong, i edited and fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(null);` at this line you cant pass context as `null`.

So Replace this

```
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(null);
```

With this one

```
MySQLiteHelper db ;
```

And initialize this inside `OnCreate()` ..

```
db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

SQLdb = getWritableDatabase();

in your insertUser() method.